# suppress confirmation dialog while using onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am using onbeforeunload event to send ajax request to perform some clean up task.

When I am using onbeforeunload, it shows the confirmation dialog on closing the tab.
What I want is not to show any confirmation dialog and just send the clean up request. Following is the script I am using.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = unloadFunction;
    function unloadFunction() {
        var test_id = $('#test_id').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/test/cleanup/" + test_id,
            cache: false
        }).done(function () {
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Is there any way I can suppress the confirmation dialog?

As per some suggestions, I have tried to change return statement to `return ;` instead of `return false;` .  But this is also not working.

Comment: Does `return null;` do what you're looking for?

Comment: return null; is not showing the dialog but also not sending the ajax call to the server.

Comment: This could be because you're calling return after the Ajax call. Remember, your Ajax call is asynchronous by default, so that return will get called before the Ajax call has completed. Pass async: false in your Ajax call settings, and you can remove the done function. You then shouldn't hit the return null until after the synchronous Ajax call has completed.

Comment: Making async:false worked. Thanks

Comment: Cool, feel free to mark my answer below as the correct one for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments on the original post, the answer is to make the call synchronous by adding `async: false` in the Ajax call settings, change the last return false to `return null;`, and remove the done function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = unloadFunction;
function unloadFunction() {
    var test_id = $('#test_id').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/test/cleanup/" + test_id,
        cache: false,
        async: false
    });

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user closes the page the document is dead, the scripts are dead. You're expecting the script to run after they close. Now if the tab doesn't close it feels like it's frozen waiting for your function to finish. Meaning it's not possible. I believe that's what you want? The clean up request won't send because the document is closed.

Comment: Currently with the above code, cleanup request is getting send because it is before unload. But it is showing the confirmation dialog whether user want to leave the page or not. I don't want that dialog to be shown.

Comment: The clean up request won't send if you don't have the pop up because the popup is what's preventing the document from closing and executing your clean up request